# grep - problems with pattern and search behaviour with terminal *

Tags: grep, wildcard

trying to `grep` files from `ls` with the first two characters as pattern, thus

```
$ ls Downloads | grep ^ub*

u6xYlgKYQOajUYzjmGQ5.pdf
ubuntu 16.04 base
ubuntu-16-04-base.iso
ubuntu-base-16.04-core-amd64.manifest
ubuntu-base-16.04-core-amd64.tar.gz
ubuntu-base-16.04-core-amd64.tar.gz.zsync
ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz
ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz.torrent
usbguard-master.zip
```

So as you can see the first and last two results are the same as I would expect from a pattern saying `first character = "u"`, not `"ub"`.

Using

```
$ ls Downloads | grep ^u*
```

just dumps out the *whole* `Downloads` contents.

Why does `^ub*` return a list of files beginning `u...`, `^u*` seems to make `grep` promiscuous, but then

```
ls Downloads | grep ^ubu*

ubuntu 16.04 base
ubuntu-16-04-base.iso
ubuntu-base-16.04-core-amd64.manifest
ubuntu-base-16.04-core-amd64.tar.gz
ubuntu-base-16.04-core-amd64.tar.gz.zsync
ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz
ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz.torrent
```

seems to work as I'd expect (and I placed a `testubu` file in `~/Downloads` to check the adherence to `^`; its apparently strict, here).

Quotes for the `PATTERN` make no difference either, which surprised me, but, ok.

And just now by accident, I find that the simplest approach is best

```
ls Downloads | grep ^ub
```

returns only files with names starting `ub...` Of course, removing the `^` returns filenames containing `...ub...` only.

I can appreciate that using `^` AND `*`, e.g. `^ub*` is redundant - `grep` looks at the start and doesn't need to care about what follows in the string.

But why

```
ls Downloads | grep ub*

bleachbit_1.12_all_ubuntu1604.deb
blue_firefox.svg
DokumentWed.pdf
Firefox_multicolour.svg
u6xYlgKYQOajUYzjmGQ5.pdf
ubuntu 16.04 base
[excerpt]
```

I can't replicate the colouring used in terminal within the code format on this forum, (and the autoeditor is fighting me to put this back into code form...), but look at the bolded characters

bleachbit_1.12_all_**ubu**nt**u**1604.deb - bl**u**e_firefox.svg - Dok**u**mentWed.pdf - Firefox_m**u**lticolo***u***r.svg - **u**6xYlgKYQOajUYzjmGQ5.pdf - **ubu**nt**u** 16.04 base

Its only searching `u` OR `ub`, not `b`.

So `*` isn't acting like the wildcard I've come to expect, but I am still pretty wet behind the ears. Also, `| grep *ub*` returned nothing but the `Public` directory, even though there are heaps of filenames with `...ub...`.

What am I misunderstanding about `*` in `grep`?

Comment: regex is not same as wildcards... see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y ... also, why do you need grep at all? looks like you need `ls Downloads/ub*` ?

Comment: `^ub*` means: must begin with `u` then followed by 0 or more `b`

Comment: @Sundeep - re .../ub* you know, I didn't know you could do that. Thankyou.

Comment: Okay, I'll learn about regex. Cheers, JD.